# Should we have a Star Trek Franchise tag for questions that relate to the entire universe of shows, movies and books?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have individual series tags for Star Trek. Should we have a Star Trek Franchise tag for questions that relate to the entire universe of shows, movies and books? I'm asking because sometimes Star Trek questions relate to the entire franchise, sometimes they are series specific. Tagging a question with Star Trek is ambigous. It can mean TOS, or it can mean everything Star Trek.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is already what the [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) tag means. For questions that are specifically about TOS, you can use [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a late answer, but you can use the appropriate tags for each series;

- [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek) for the whole Star Trek universe, including books, films, TV, Games, RPG and other media
- [star-trek-tos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tos) for questions relating to the "Star Trek : The Original Series" TV series
- [star-trek-tng](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tng) for questions relating to "Star Trek : The Next Generation" TV series and films
- [star-trek-voyager](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-voyager) for questions relating to the "Star Trek : Voyager" TV series
- [star-trek-ds9](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-ds9) for questions relating to the "Star Trek : DS9" TV series
- [star-trek-tas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-tas) for questions relating to the "Star Trek : The Animated Series" TV series
- [star-trek-enterprise](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-enterprise) for questions relating to the "Star Trek : Enterprise" TV series

There are also individual tags for the recent feature films;

- [star-trek-2009](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-2009) for questions relating to the rebooted "Star Trek" 2009 film
- [star-trek-into-darkness](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek-into-darkness) for questions relating to the "Star Trek into Darkness" film

Comment: "We have individual series tags for Star Trek." Sounds like we had the appropriate tags for each series back then too.