# How should Netflix's Death Note movie be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, the [death-note](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-note) tag reads as follows:

> Questions regarding the manga and anime adaptation of Death Note

Note that this tag is currently used only 7 times, so it's not very popular.

But with the recent release of an American live adaptation, there arises the question: how to properly tag it?

The storyline diverges a lot between main material and [the 2017 movie](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt1241317/), so a new tag might be justified. But then remain the [cases of the other movies](http://asianwiki.com/Death_Note), [video games,](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Video_Games) and potential future adaptations.

Updating the current tag to include movies and games might be simpler, seeing its low usage.

Comment: `death-note-2017` - simple and unambiguous.

Answer (score 14):

We have a couple of choices here.

1. We could simply expand the tag definition to include the [movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Note_(2017_film)) as well;

   > ("*Questions regarding the manga, anime **and other** adaptations of Death Note*")

   or
2. We could create a new tag for the film - [death-note-2017](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-note-2017) to distinguish it.

---

Given that there are likely to be more questions about the film than about the Manga or Anime combined and given that the film is ***not*** going to be a faithful rendition of the manga (unlike the anime which was pretty close), **an entirely new tag seems the wise route to go down.**

Comment: *title-year* is our naming convention, so #2 is the right answer. We've also used it for other Netflix titles

Comment: It's not a series - it's a feature-length film. though I think folks who made it are still considering a sequel.

Comment: @Gallifreyan - Oops. Shoulda looked harder

Comment: I myself only learned that the day after the release.

Comment: #1 seems more reasonable. We don't have separate tag for the 2006 movie either. Maybe we could add 'movie' or 'parody' tag if we want to discuss the 2017 adaptation.

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0 ouch!

Comment: @D.O.B.Y2.0  Our tagging policy is each individual work gets its own tag. #1 ignores that. We could use `death-note` as a *franchise* tag, but the new movie needs its own, too, minimum.

Comment: @CreationEdge oh? That's good news. I didnt know we had a clearly defined policy on tags.

Comment: If a question is specifically about the movie, and not "Death Note" as a whole, it should be using a "death-note-2017" tag. You wouldn't want every question about Star Wars to be using just a "Star Wars" tag, after all.

Comment: @Creationedge - Our policy is that each work *can* have its own tag, not necessarily that they all do.

Comment: @Valorum all book works apparently have their own, and many to most movies, although I think there is a policy that says they **all** should.

Comment: @valorum No, the policy is all works should have their own tag, but we've grandfathered in some exceptions, or outright allow general exceptions, for things like trilogies, or individual runs of comic books (we generally collapse to the main character).

Comment: @CreationEdge - Clicky-link, please

Comment: [this seems to be related](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/how-should-we-handle-tag-hierarchies)

Comment: Same one we bring up every time there's a discussion on individual works... https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/31178

Comment: @Gallifreyan but it's so terrible, I hope no sequel come

Comment: @AegonTargaryen My wife and I quite enjoyed it. But, then again, we never saw any of the original media it's based on so we had some fresh eyes on it.