# Can we get an [ancillary-sword] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we get an `[ancillary-sword]` tag to go with the [ancillary-justice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancillary-justice) and [ancillary-mercy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancillary-mercy) tags?

Comment: What prevents you from just creating the tag? The need for it seems quite apparent from the existence of the other tags listed in your question.

Comment: Doh — I didn't realize [I had that ability](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancillary-sword)!

Comment: You get the ability to create tags at [300 reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) :-)

Comment: I have a feeling there's too much tags around here. Just the tag for Imperial Radch would do.

Comment: @Mithoron We should follow whatever the site policy is for trilogies, etc. For example what does it do with LotR or HDM?

Comment: It looks like if we remove the individual book tags for this we have a lot of cleanup to do throughout: Those and many other others have tags for each book.

Comment: Did I say anything about this policy? What I said is about tag making. Tags are made when they're needed and tag for 1 or even 3 questions isn't particularly useful when there's a bigger tag with still only 10 q.

Comment: @Mithoron I'm not sure what you mean by "needed". Having a convenient way to find out that there are only a few questions about something is pretty helpful, imv. But if that's the site policy, sure. (Though I'm not sure it is: most [new SO tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), for example, have less than 3 questions.)

Comment: That's just my ideas: adding first author tag, second franchise, third separate instalments when number of questions grows.

Comment: @Mithoron Like I said, whatever the site policy is.

Comment: Well, there was this https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4860/how-should-we-handle-tag-hierarchies but SE communities aren't all that rules-driven, ultimately things are kinda fluid...

Comment: @Mithoron To clarify here the tagging currently used is fine. Franchise/series tag + book tags is perfectly acceptable. Different works handle this differently but if the precedent is already set for series + work then we should follow that. Importantly we should always try and use the series/franchise tag in any case. Lastly, author tags are only really to be used on questions about the author. There are a few exceptions to this but they don't apply in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

As you found out you already had the required reputation (300) for the [Create Tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege and so have since created it. See: [ancillary-sword](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ancillary-sword).

In the future when you create the tag you can also [edit the tag wiki](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/6567) to add in a usage excerpt to describe how the tag should be used. Please do so as this helps other users work out when to use the tag!